# Implement IEntityWithKey with POCO template

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

I (for me, quite surprisingly) have never seen any questions or blog posts about this.

Is it possible to modify the POCO T4 template in a way that POCO classes implement the IEntityWithKey interface? I would like to do this in order to be able to attach entities directly to the ObjectContext.

Is this possible? What are the drawbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't see any question about this because implementing the interface will mean that your entity is not persistent ignorant any more (which is main reason to use POCO) because it would expose persistent related property dependent on Entity framework. That is the reason why nobody use it with POCO template.

But yes it is possible to implement this interface.